# How to redirect with HttpContext

Tags: asp.net

My questions are:

1. So I need to create a custom class / HttpHandler and throw this code in it?  Or can I place this somewhere else like in the global.asax?
2. How do I check for the Host (so check for www.mydomain.com) incoming so I know when to redirect?

Code:

```
if ("comes from certain domain")
{
  context.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
  context.Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://www.testdomain.com/Some.aspx");
}
```

Comment: You probably want a context.Response.StatusCode = 302 in there too.

Answer (score 1):

Paste this into a new .cs file in your App_Code folder:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class TestModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        if (app.Request.Url.Host == "example.com") {
            app.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            app.Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://www.testdomain.com/Some.aspx");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
    }
}
```

Then add this to your web.config in system.web:

```
<httpModules>
     <add type="TestModule" name="TestModule" />
</httpModules>
```

Comment: I'm not crazy about adding the _context field in this way. Your context_BeginRequest method already receives an HttpApplication object as its sender parameter.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll update it. (I just whipped this up quick from memory and couldn't remember the details)

Comment: we're not using an App_Code folder.  We are using WAP thank God ;).  Why not just add to global.asax which is what Phaedrus has confirmed will work?  I actually just tested it myself and I see no need for a class for this...it's too much.

Comment: As long as you only have one requirement sure. If you have more than one module-type requirement the Global.asax file gets really cluttered. This gives you something reusable between projects too.

Comment: If you're just using WAP, you can create this class anywhere in the proejct.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to place it in the `Global.asax`, in the `Application_BeginRequest` event.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    string host = context.Request.Url.Host;
    if (host == "www.mydomain.com")
    {
        context.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Location", 
                              "http://www.testdomain.com/Some.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I avoid putting anything unnecessary in global.asax as it tends to get cluttered. Instead, create an HttpModule, add an event handler

```
public void Init(System.Web.HttpApplication app)
{
    app.BeginRequest += new System.EventHandler(Rewrite_BeginRequest);
}
```

and, in the beginRequest method,

```
public void Rewrite_BeginRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
{
   HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
   /// all request properties now available through app.Context.Request object

}
```